# Form doesn't post if keyboard is open on Android devices

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, forms, form-submit

I have online application (bunch of forms) developed (in ASP.net, C#) for desktops. Lately, I was asked to optimize forms to work nicely on mobile devices. 
Forms have "Previous" and "Next" buttons on the bottom that allow user to go to next or previous form. These buttons are asp.net LinkButtons that trigger OnClick server event.

**Problem:**

When editing any text field and when Android keybord is open, if I scroll down and press "Next" button, keyboard closes and field that was edited regains the focus. I have to scroll down to push "Next" button again in order to go to the next form.

For example. If I just give focus (click) to field, but don't enter any text or if I remove one or more characters, "Next" button will work even if keyboard is open. But if I click at text field and type at least one character, Next button won't work when I click it first time. It will work second time.

It is very annoying. Does anybody know what is happening with these android devices? This is not occurring on iPhones.

There is nothing special about the code...

```
<form id="ApplicationForm" onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" action="./Application" method="post">
...
<input name="HighSchool" class="form-control" id="HighSchool" type="text" maxlength="50" value="">
...
<input type="submit" name="btnPrev" value="Prev" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;btnPrev&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="btnPrev" />
<input type="submit" name="btnNext" value="Next" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;btnNext&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="btnNext" />
</form>
```

Thanks

Comment: Some code examples would be nice

Comment: I updated my post. Thanks.